# Exporting Treemap chart

Tags: svg, highcharts, export, treemap

We have four options for Highcharts exporting. PNG, JPEG, PDF & SVG. When we do the export and print the image, the scaling is not consistent for other charts. i have set the exporting sourceWidth to 2000.

```
exporting:{
sourceWidth:2000
}
```

This does prints the image in landscape mode but the labels and legend are hard to read. Is there a better way to scale the chart for pdf and png image type so it is better looking and easier to read?

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle example of this behavior?

Comment: You can reconfigure [scale](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.scale) parameter or set [exported charts options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions) like fontSize etc.